# Visiting Istanbul for a few hours while on a layover with Turkish Airlines - how do I get a visa, if I need one?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, turkey, turkish-airlines

I am an Indian passport holder. I am travelling to Greece via Istanbul (Turkish Airline) from 10th to 25th June. My return flight to New Delhi from Athens has an 8 hour layover and I am considering applying for a transit Visa to take a look around Istanbul for a couple of hours. However, my Schengen Visa application is already under process and I haven't declared on the Schengen Visa application form that I intend to apply for a Turkey transit Visa. Will it pose a problem? If not, can I apply for an e-Visa and get a transit Visa for Turkey online? What do I need to keep in mind? This is my first international travel and any advice is appreciated.
Thanks!
Sruti

Comment: Might also be related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67933/32134

Comment: The proposed dupe is does not answer the question. This Q is worded wrongly, they are seeking a tourist visa to look around, i.e. more than a transit visa. The other Q is for a transit visa without leaving the airport.