# I want to visit Turkey during a 13h layover

Tags: visas, transit-visas, turkey, yemeni-citizens

I am from Yemen and I am traveling from Russia to Malaysia with Turkish airlines and I have a transit in Turkey for 13 hours, I searched in the Internet and I found that it's possible to get e-visa, but while I am filling the information it asked me for

"I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents."

And I am going from Russia so how can I get e-visa ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you found refers to holders of a valid visa of Ireland, US, UK or Schengen area. If you only have a Russian and Malaysian visa, then you need to apply for a regular Turkish visa.

More detailed info is provided in this [Q](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67933/32134)&[A](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67944/32134)

Comment: I have passed thro turkey and now I am in Malaysia and that was true , I needed to apply for regular visa before I traveled .. Thanks for your info