# Tourist Visa while returning to India from Sweden

Tags: indian-citizens, turkey, tourist-visas, e-visas

I traveled to Sweden from Mumbai on the 29th of July and I had a 22 hours stay in Turkey and as I had a valid Schengen visa I could apply for a tourist visa and spent a day in Turkey

Now I am returning to Mumbai on the 8th August and my duration of the Schengen visa of 11 days is completed but my Schengen Visa is Valid till 20th August and I want to stay in Turkey for 3-4 days which is still in the validity of my Schengen visa. My doubt is as Indians are only allowed a E-Visa or a visa on arrival only if we have a valid Schengen visa ...

Will I be issued an entry into Turkey on my way back?

Comment: No i have only 1 Single entry Visa

Comment: i have been having a doubt regarding the fact that once i leave the schengen territory if it gets cancelled

Comment: Your best bet is probably to ask a Turkish consulate about the rules pertaining to single-entry Schengen visas.

Comment: I think your question is basically answered here: [http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67933/32134](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67933/32134) and by the [comment of @pnuts](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76069/tourist-visa-while-returning-to-india-from-sweden#comment166041_76069), i.e. your Schengen visa will no longer be considered "valid" (the interpretation is up to the immigration officer in the end), so no you can not get the e-Visa IMHO.

Comment: It had neither expired nor been cancelled (fortunately!) It was spent, that's completely different (to see the distinction, consider this: it could still get annulled at any time during the stay or even on exit, making any further stay illegal and adding a record suggesting it was obtained fraudulently to the Schenven Visa Information System).

Answer (score 1):

You were eligible for an e-Visa for Turkey before use of your Schengen visa because you were able to confirm:

> I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.

Since that visa was single-entry it expired on your entry to Sweden, therefore does not qualify you for an e-Visa on return to India. Instead you would need to go through the [Pre-Application System for Turkish Sticker Visa](https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Visa/Index). Without that, as I fear you may already have discovered, you will not be allowed entry.